# When running jar program from java code, the jar program's gui freezes on direct input

Tags: java, runtime.exec

To understand the situation, I try to describe what I'm trying to achieve:
I would like to create a java program that starts another java program (a minecraft server), monitors it's output, and sends commands to it's input accordingly.

I was able to start the jar program from my code, and I was also able to write an output listener for it, that currently only prints the jar program's output to the console.

The jar program I'm running from my code has a gui with a text output panel, where it shows messages, and an input field (textarea) where I can give commands. My problem is that when I start my code and it starts the program everything works fine until I want to write directly into the program's input field. If I type any letter into the input field, the gui freezes.

What do I wrong?

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting.");
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("java -jar \"D:\\Program Files\\mc\\minecraft_server.jar\"");
        // output both stdout and stderr data from proc to stdout of this process
        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream());
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream());
        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The output reader:

```
public class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    InputStream is;

    // reads everything from is until empty.
    StreamGobbler(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, merge the `out` & `err` stream. Actually seeing 2 streams there, I foolishly thought that the gobblers were consuming both the output streams, but of course it is reading `err` & `in`.  ***Consume the `out` stream!***  And go through the linked article from the [exec info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) & implement all the other recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, but the question remains: Why does the gui freeze? I'm simply running the program. I'm not tempering anything...

Comment: Good on you for implementing my advice and editing the question.. Oh wait, you did not bother.  *"the question remains:"*  Well, you're the one who has a distinct motivation to solve it, so I'd get on to those things recommended in comment 1.  Good luck!

Comment: Okay. I merged the streams. This obviously has nothing to do with the problem, it's just an optimalization. What I don't understand why should I consume the out strem? When I tunnelled the out into a reader and tried to read it nothing happened, but when I read the "input stream" (what seems to be the output stream from the jar's view) everything just works fine. I get all the messages the jar sends. I'll implement the other things, but I would like to start with this.

Comment: *"I'll implement the other things, but I would like to start with this."*  Start with implementing 'the other things', because, as I wrote in the linked page.. *"The article is the **first** thing to check if a process fails. Implement **all** the tips.."*

Comment: Okay, I red it and I'm not closer to the solution:
-My program does not wait an exit value. I have nothing to do with it.
-The program reads the whole err and out.
-I do not want to pass any parameters or execute commands upon startup.

What I want:
-Start a server from my automated manager (that runs until I tell it otherwise)
-Get what it says (this is working)
-Send inputs when desired (this will be a next step)
-In the meantime the original surface should remain responsible (in case if I need to interact directly, and not thru the automated manager) <This is what is not working...

Comment: ...I really appreciate the support you gave me but It did not give me any understanding about this.

The only thing I can think of is that the output (input) reader is the one that blocks the program. But why does it not bluck the gui when it displays the messages or move the window around? Why only when I type in a letter? If I close the output handler, how do I start it again when the program has something to say, from where will I know it?

Comment: Show the latest code as an edit to the question.  A complete (short) code is better than snippets.

Comment: And bingo... The reader is the guilty.

Comment: I showed the whole code...
First is the main class, second is the gobbler. Main guns the program and the gobbler. That's all.

It turned out that even if I start the gobbler in a new thread it will block the program until it exits. Probably some kind of a listener would be better than simply reading the output forever. Nvm, I'll try to work around. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, instead of using the stream gobbler, just inherit the process's io:

```
final ProcessBuilder p1 = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO();
p1.start();
```

If you don't care about stdin/out, use this to direct everything to NUL (windows version of /dev/null):

```
p1.redirectInput(Redirect.from(new File("NUL"))).redirectOutput(Redirect.to(new File("NUL")))
                        .redirectError(Redirect.to(new File("NUL")));
```

Does the program still crash?